# My checkboxinput value does not work

Tags: shiny

I have a small shiny application which plot a graph with a log scale when the variable 'logEch' is "x".

This works:

```
output$plot <- renderPlot({
    logEch<-"x"
    Plotfigure(XHydrau,DataQs, ParHydrau, Rescal,logEch)
})
```

But when I  affect the value "x" from the inputcheckbox 'xlog':

```
output$plot <- renderPlot({
  if(input$xlog){logEch<-"x"}
  Plotfigure(XHydrau,DataQs, ParHydrau, Rescal,logEch)
})
```

I obtain the error message: `argument is of length zero`

What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: Is the ID of your checkboxInput really "xlog"?

Answer (score 0):

As you have not posted full [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) i can only assume where the problem lays...

I guess you need to expand your if statement --> there must be if...else... arguments!

so i would add to `renderPlot`:

```
if(input$xlog){logEch<-"x"}else{NULL}
```